# AngularJS Resolve

Tags: angular-services, angular-promise

I'm creating my frist AngularJS application.

I have a kind of problem with my Index page.
There can be two different templates depending if User is authenticated or not.

My idea is to have a `MainController` defined before ng-view and a view controller (indexController, aboutController, ...) depending which view is displayed.

I've made a service `UserService` which mission is to get user's data from my server and serve them to controllers.

The problem is I want my **MainController** to get the user's data.

I've read things about `resolve` and `promise` but it only works with view controllers because it's defined in `$routeProvider`.

My question is how can I initialize my `MainController` data before executing my app routes ?

PS : A bit of code to help

**index.html**

```
<div id="page" ng-controller="MainController as Main"> 
    <div id="navbar-container" class="shadow1">
        <navbar></navbar>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="page-container" class="large-12 columns">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**mainController.js**

```
...
define([], function()
{
    return angular.module('MyApp.controllers', []).controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', 'UserService', function($scope, $http, UserService)
    {
        // I want this to be defined before executing the app //
        $scope.currentUser = UserService.getCurrentUser();
    }]);
});
...
```

**userService.js**

```
define(['angular'], function (angular)
{
    return angular.module('MyApp.services', []).service('UserService', ['$http', function($http)
        {
            var _currentUser = null;
            var _promise = (_currentUser !== null) ? _currentUser : $http.get('/api/user').success(function(data)
            {
                _currentUser = data.result;
            });
            return {
                promise : _promise,
                getCurrentUser : function()
                {
                    return _currentUser;
                },
                isAuthenticated : function()
                {
                    return (_currentUser !== null);
                },
            };
        }
    ]);
});
```

Maybe there is another way to do what I expect but i'm really a noob with AngularJS. I really would appreciate some help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to write $scope.currentUser = UserService.getCurrentUser(); line in run() method of angular js which is first fire when application load

Comment: I tried this. That worked yesterday but it was because of luck. Today i noticed my data are loaded after page started rendering. Is there a way to wait for data before rendering ?

Comment: For that try to write that line in $rootScope.$on method which is define inside the run method

Answer (score 0):

Actually Config blocks run before run blocks. This is only relevant if you are trying to resolve in ng-route or ui-router.

> 1. **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration
>      phase. Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to
>      prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.
> 2. **Run blocks** - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the
>      application. Only instances and constants can be injected into run blocks. This is to prevent
>      further system configuration during application run time.

[Line 122](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/ce669edfa14dc7eb7c389d2f82c9c98399a9009b/docs/content/guide/module.ngdoc)